# Polymer/Paper dropdown not working properly on IE10

Tags: polymer

Can't see the value inside the input and the menu has horizontal scrollbars, even with small words.

Have you experienced the same issue and found a solution?

I opened a [thread](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-dropdown-menu/issues/64) on github project if anyone interested.

Here is some code I used (this code is a part of a larger module and I use webcomponents.js to make it work):

`<dom-module id="test-form">`

`<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">`

```
<template>
            <paper-dropdown-menu label="Center">
                <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
                        <paper-item>Item 1</paper-item>
                        <paper-item>Item 2</paper-item>
                </paper-menu>
            </paper-dropdown-menu>

</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "test-form"
    });
</script>
```

`</dom-module>`

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

[Edited to remove parts about wc being supported by polymer on IE10, since accepted answer changed]

Your component name must include a dash.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I edited my initial post and i use IE10. I also added the code I use.

Comment: You have to have dashes in your web component names, can't just name it form. Also, I'd separate out the non working code into a separate project to debug the issue better if you're still having problems.

Comment: I changed the name of my form. It's not the initial name of it I just typed it for the example.

Answer (score -1):

Polymer is based on http://webcomponents.org/. You can see that IE and Safari  do not support it. EDGE will probably support it, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: Thanks, webcomponents.org has an "under consideration" flag for IE/Edge but if you click for more details, you can see that it's not supported. I have never seen that before.